# Delay in getting text on text box textchanged event - Windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, viewmodel

I created a `TextBox`. I wrote a `TextChanged` event in view model. The problem is, when I type `'a'` in the `TextBox`, in the `TextChanged` event, I am getting "". Then if I type next letter `'b'`, I am getting the previous result `'a'` and If I type the next letter `'c'`, I am getting `'ab'` as result. Why is one char delay in the `TextChanged` event?

Here is my XAML code:

```
<toolkit:PhoneTextBox Visibility="{Binding IsSearchBoxVisible,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" TextChanged="txtboxPhoneContacts_TextChanged" Grid.Row="2" Width="450" FontSize="28" Foreground="Black" x:Name="txtboxPhoneContacts" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Background="LightGray" Hint="{Binding Localizedresources.SearchContactsText,Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Text="{Binding PhoneContactSearchText,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" Style="{StaticResource SearchTextBoxStyle}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PhoneBookTextBoxTextChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text,ElementName=txtboxPhoneContacts,BindsDirectlyToSource=True}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <controls:UpdateOnTextChangedBehavior></controls:UpdateOnTextChangedBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</toolkit:PhoneTextBox>
```

My `ViewModel.cs`

```
private void OnPhoneBookTextBoxTextChanged(Object obj)
{
        if (obj != null)
        {
            String text = obj.ToString();

            searchResults = new ObservableCollection<PhoneBookEntity>(
                             from item in PhoneContactsList
                             where item.PhoneContactName.Contains(text)
                             select item);
        }
}
```

Any suggestions is highly appreciated.